# (Fixed) Knife project removes vertex points but leaves faces untouched

Tags: mesh, faces

So I am trying to make a hole for my barrel but whenever I use the knife the faces I selected stay but the vertex points get removed, not sure what causes this and restarting blender didn't fix it.
[image: Before I use the knife[![][1]]

Here is the file
[image]

Comment: can you share the blend file? maybe something wrong with model...

Comment: as far as I can see, you have some modelling issues. You were modelling with modifiers activated. Also, the interior of the gun is a different object. You have to merge/join those objects then perform the knife project. To join models select the desired objects, and press ctrl+j.

Comment: Thanks so much for pointing that out, not sure what I did to create 2 of the same objects but that was the problem, cheers

Comment: remember that modifiers/editions/etc will work on a object at a time, that's why join meshes might be what you need